# linking a domain to php instead of localhost

Tags: php

*I am new to php and I know this is a really stupid question to ask and I can be thrown out of the stack overflow community for this, but I'll ask it anyway.
Normally when we connect to localhost we write*

```
    if(!mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password) || !mysql_select_db('user_transaction'))
    {
    echo 'Cannot process the requested operation';
    }
    else
   {
   // other code..
   }
```

***But I want to connect to a domain in place of localhost like `"http://myownsite.com"` . **Can anyone please tell me as how can I achieve this?*****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to know where the mySQL is running on your remote host...   for example, the most common way to connect to a mySQL database is using mysql.yoursitename.com.    So your code would look like this:

```
mysql_connect('mysql.myownsite.com',$username,$password)
```

If you have your mySQL running on some *other* subdomain, just adjust as needed.  But the above would be the most common way.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to remote database you just have to replace "localhost" with your remote server's IP/hostname.

For example

```
mysql_connect('myownsite.com',$username,$password)
```

Three important things:

1. You provide an IP address od hostname without any protocol like "http" etc.
2. Your remote server needs to be configured to accept incoming connections on MySQL's port (`iptables` usually).
3. You remote MySQL server also needs to be configured to accept remote connections (my.ini).

P.S.

`mysql` extention is deprecated for long time. You should not use it at all. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Idid what you said, but it shows me the error  'no such host is known'.

Answer (score 0):

just use :

```
mysql_connect('myownsite.com',$username,$password)
```

Comment: did what you told, but it shows an error no such host is known